# ThunderBird Event for Viewing a Message

Tags: javascript, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm trying to modify a message before it is displayed in the main window in Thunderbird.  I can't seem to find 1) An event that will be triggered when a new message is opened/viewed 2) A way to modify the displayed contents of a message.

I believe I need the `chrome://messenger/content/messenger.xul` overlay, and can use a listener such as:

```
window.addEventListener( "SOME MAGIC HERE", modify_message_handler, true );
```

But what that event is, I am unsure, along with what object I will get (a message header?) and how easily I can modify what is displayed.

So the questions are:

- Do I have the correct overlay?
- Can this be done with events?  If not, how?
- If so, what event is needed and what object does it pass?

Comment: have you found https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference ?

Comment: @john.k.doe I hadn't seen that, thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If what you want is something similar to a Greasemonkey script that would run on every message, you should:

1. Wait for the `load` event of the `window`.
2. Retrieve the message pane object with `document.getElementById("messagepane")`.
3. Bind your handler to the message pane's `DOMContentLoaded` event, or similar events like `load` depending on when exactly you want your handler to be called. `DOMContentLoaded` will give you a Greasemonkey-style behavior.
4. In the event handler, `event.originalTarget` is the document corresponding to the displayed message. You can apply all the usual DOM modification techniques here.

For more details, see [this example](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load) from the documentation.

Comment: That appears to be the entry point I need - I'll give it a go (in due time) and report back.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear where you've tried looking yet, but I'll offer a suggestion: [this outdated documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Thunderbird/Mail_event_system) suggests there is an OnItemPropertyChanged event that you could tap into to listen for the "open" property, which does appear to be defined in [the source](http://lxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/mailnews/base/src/nsMsgFolderDataSource.cpp#920).

Whether this only applies to folders or both folders and messages, though, is unclear; and you'll have to dig deeper to find out if the properties of the item object passed in will allow you to make changes.

Hope that sheds some light; if you've already been all over that, please let us know what you've learned.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I will report back but it might not be for some days - I'm juggling some tasks right now.

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370903/thunderbird-event-for-viewing-a-message/11514251#11514251 for what I found.

Answer (score 3):

*I'll primarily address the **`thunderbird-extension`** Tag in your Question.*

Thunderbird Extension author [**Paolo "Kaosmos"**](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/index-en.html) has many ready to use tools for your consideration.

---

[**HeaderToolsLite:**](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/headertoolslite-en.html)

> The editing features (changing headings only or the **entire source code
>   of the message**) are accessible from the menu "Message" ->
>   "HeaderToolsLite" or from the context menu in message panel.
>
> The edit function of the entire source code should be used with
>   caution, because a wrong change can cause problems in displaying all
>   the messages in the folder.

---

[**Attach Extra Tools:**](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/index-en.html)

```
attach easily messages selected in the main window<br />
attach attachments from other messages<br />
attach files from 5 favourite directories<br />
attach files and directories in zipped format<br />
```

---

[**DSN OPTIONS GUI:**](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/index-en.html)

> an extension that adds a graphical interface to handle the
>   preferences, both global and per account, about "***Delivery Status
>   Notification***" (**DSN**).

---

***Useful Links:***
**Notable Reference 1:** [**Common use cases to modify messages**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/HowTos#section_5) 
**Notable Reference 2:** [**Thunderbird API for Message Window and Message Header**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/An_overview_of_the_Thunderbird_interface#Message_window)
**Notable Reference 3:** [**Building a Thunderbird Extension**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension)
**Notable Reference 4:** [**Using XUL Thunderbird UI in your Extension**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension_5%3a_XUL)

Answer (score 2):

Generic Human set me down the right path with the badly needed link.  First thing was to add a `load` event.  I'll paste some of the code with my very primitive understanding:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event) {
        window.removeEventListener("load", load, false);
        myExtension.init();
}, false);
```

When this script's overlay loads, run `init`.

```
var myExtension = {
  init: function() {
        var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent"); // browser app content
        if (appcontent) {
                appcontent.addEventListener("OMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);
        }
        var messagepane = document.getElementById("messagepane"); // tunderbird message pane
        if(messagepane) {
                messagepane.addEventListener("load", function(event) { myExtension.onPageLoad(event); }, true);
        }
  },
```

In `init` I add a listener that calls `onPageLoad` every time a message is displayed.  I don't actually use the `appcontent` case afaik.

```
  onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
                var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;  // doc is document that triggered "onload" event
                // we can now morph the loaded page
                // doc.location is a 'Location' object
                var newDat = mutateBody(doc.body.innerHTML);
                doc.body.innerHTML = newDat;
                aEvent.originalTarget.defaultView.addEventListener("unload", function(event) { myExtension.onPageUnload(event); }, true);
  },

  onPageUnload: function(aEvent) {
    // No action necessary yet
  }
};
```

The `doc.body.textContents` seemed an obvious element but it actually didn't maintain formatting (darn HTML) - using `innerHTML` works much better for my needs.

Comment: Mozilla documentation for this can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load